# Reducing size of ZPL data sent to printer

Tags: c#, zpl

Trying to send data to a zpl printer using the GFR zpl command but the image data string is very large and it takes a long pause after each label print.
Is there a way to optimize the data within the data string for repeated values in C#, so the size of the image and the time taken to download to printer is reduced?

Comment: Choose a smaller image?

Comment: Have you already tried to encode your payload in Z64? https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf around page 1318

Comment: Do you have any examples in C#? please?

Comment: No, I have not. Before you asked this question I never heard of ZPL or Z64 but the docs seems pretty informative so it shouldn't be to hard for you to get something out of that.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the image on the printer is the best way if you're printing the image multiple times. You're only sending the image data to the printer once, and every subsequent label can be send much faster.

[Here](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7893&actp=RSS)'s an article showing how to save an image using Zebra Setup Utilities. It also covers how to print a saved image using ZPL:

`^XA^FO50,50^XGE:ZEBRA.GRF^FS^XZ`

if ZEBRA.GRF is the image.

If you're using Zebra's Link-OS SDK, you can also store the image in your program using their [GraphicsUtil](http://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/latest/pc/). There's some sample code included in that documentation, but basically there's a `storeImage()` function you can use with the image path or  ZebraImageI object.